# Interpolation error: Prove that $|f(t)−p(t)| \leq \frac{1}{24} \underset{\xi \in [t_0,t_2]}{\max}|f^{(4)}(\xi)||(t−t_0)(t−t_1)^2(t−t_2)|$

Tags: interpolation

> Let $f \in \mathcal{C}^4(\mathbb{R})$ be a real valued function, let $t_0< t_1< t_2$ be real numbers and $p$ is a polynomial of  degree $≤3$,  which  satisfies $p(t_j)=f(t_j) , \ j=  0,1,2$  and $p'(t_1)  =f'(t_1)$.
>
> a) Prove that for $t \in [t_0,t_2]$, $$|f(t)−p(t)| \leq \frac{1}{24} \underset{\xi \in [t_0,t_2]}{\max}|f^{(4)}(\xi)||(t−t_0)(t−t_1)^2(t−t_2)|$$
>
> b) Furthermore, is there a function $f \in \mathcal{C}^4(\mathbb{R})$, $f \not\in \mathcal{P_3}$ and a corresponding polynomial $p \in \mathcal{P_3}$ and a $t \in (t_0,t_2), \ t \neq t_1$, for which you have equality in the above inequality?

Here is my attempt at proving a).

We wish to prove that the error of the interpolation polynomial satisfies:
\begin{align}
    |f(t) - p(t)| \; \leq \frac{1}{24} \; \ \underset{t \in [t_0,t_2]}{\max} \ |f^{(4)} (\xi)| \ |(t-t_0)(t-t_1)^2(t-t_2)|
\end{align}

We fix a value $x \in [t_0,t_2]$ and introduce the following auxiliary function
\begin{align}
    F(t) = e(t) - \underbrace{\frac{f(x)-p(x)}{(x-t_0)(x-t_1)^2(x-t_2)}}_{c} \underbrace{(t-t_0)(t-t_1)^2(t-t_2)}_{w(t)}
\end{align}
where $e(t) = f(x) - p(x)$. We note that $c$ does not depend on $t$, but on a fixed value of $x$ which makes $c$ a constant.

At the points $t_i, \ i=0,1,2$, we have $F(t_i) = e(t_i) - cw(t_i) = 0-c \cdot 0 = 0$. We have a double zero from the $(t-t_1)^2$ term in $c$. Furthermore, $F$ has a zero at the fixed value $x \in [t_0,t_2]$ since
\begin{align*}
    F(x) &= e(x) -\frac{f(x)-p(x)}{(x-t_0)(x-t_1)^2(x-t_2)} (x-t_0)(x-t_1)^2(x-t_2)\\
    &= e(x) - (f(x) - p(x))\\
    &= 0
\end{align*}
Thus, $F(t)$ has five zeroes in $[t_0,t_2]$.

By Rolle's theorem, $F'(t)$ will have four zeroes: one in the interval $[t_0,t_1]$ and one in the interval $[t_1,t_2]$, and yet another one since $t_1$ is a double root. Furthermore, we have the extra condition that $f'(t_1) = p'(t_1)$, we have that $f'(t_1) - p'(t_1) = e'(t_1) = 0$. Applying Rolle's theorem again to $F''(t)$, we get three zeroes, $F^{(3)}(t)$ has two zeroes and finally we see that $F^{(4)}(t)$ has one zero, which we denote $xi$, i.e. $F^{(4)}(\xi) = 0$.

As we are differentiating, we pay close attention to $w(t)$, which is a polynomial of degree 4. Differentiating, we get
\begin{align*}
    w'(t) &= 4t^3 + \dots\\
    w''(t) &= 12t^2 + \dots\\
    w^{(3)}(t) &= 24t + \dots\\
    w^{(4)}(t) &= 24 \\
\end{align*}

So we have $$F^{(4)}(\xi) = e^{(4)}(\xi) - 24c$$
and so
$$
c \ = \ \frac{e^{(4)}(\xi)}{24} \; \left( = \frac{f(x)-p(x)}{(x-t_0)(x-t_1)^2(x-t_2)} \right)
$$

Thus
\begin{align*}
F^{(4)}(\xi) &= \frac{e^{(4)}(\xi)}{24} =  \frac{f(x)-p(x)}{(x-t_0)(x-t_1)^2(x-t_2)}\\
\iff f(x)-p(x) &=  \frac{e^{(4)}(\xi)}{24} \cdot (x-t_0)(x-t_1)^2(x-t_2) \\
& \leq \frac{1}{24} \underset{\xi \in [t_0,t_2]}{\max}|f^{(4)}(\xi)||(t-t_0)(t−t_1)^2(t−t_2)|\\
\end{align*}

---

I'm not entirely convinced I've done this correctly, so I'm happy to accept some hints. Also, I have no idea how to approach b), so please share any tips!

Comment: How did you obtain the inequality in your last step?

Comment: @fwd It's a bit of a guess, but I'm thinking that since $e^{(4)} = f^{(4)} - p^{(4)}$ then the max is when $p^{(4)} = 0$?